# How to Compare between String object and literal using hex values

Tags: java, jsp, ntlm

The code shown below gets username from system using NTLM Windows authentication method, I need to compare username (current_user_eid).

Applying intern() method for preset value seems working for initialised values.

The String comparison between the literal string and object string gives me false as output, but on the screen they give the same output.

```
<%@ page import="sun.misc.BASE64Encoder" %>
<%
String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
String current_user_eid= null;
if (auth == null) {
        response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM");
        return;
}
if (auth.startsWith("NTLM")) { 
    byte[] msg = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(auth.substring(5));
    int off = 0, length, offset;

    if (msg[8] == 1) { 
        off = 18;
        byte z = 0;
        byte[] msg1 =
            {(byte)'N', (byte)'T', (byte)'L', (byte)'M', (byte)'S',
            (byte)'S', (byte)'P', z,
            (byte)2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z,
            (byte)40, z, z, z, (byte)1, (byte)130, z, z,
            z, (byte)2, (byte)2, (byte)2, z, z, z, z, // 
            z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z};

        response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM " + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(msg1).trim());
        return;
    } 
    else if (msg[8] == 3) { 
        off = 30;
        length = msg[off+17]*256 + msg[off+16];
        offset = msg[off+19]*256 + msg[off+18];
        current_user_eid = new String(msg, offset, length);
    } 
    else
        return;

    length = msg[off+1]*256 + msg[off];
    offset = msg[off+3]*256 + msg[off+2];
    current_user_eid = new String(msg, offset, length);
    length = msg[off+9]*256 + msg[off+8];
    offset = msg[off+11]*256 + msg[off+10];
    current_user_eid = new String(msg, offset, length); //current system user name "yaseer"

    // String Comparison starts here....

    String hard_str = new String("yaseer"); // 
    String hard_str_in=hard_str.intern();

    String eid_str=new String(current_user_eid.toString()); //passing the fetched username which is yaseer
    String eid_str_in = eid_str.intern(); // system username 

    String comp_str = "yaseer"; // String for comparison

    System.out.println(hard_str_in == comp_str); // give true

    System.out.println(eid_str_in == comp_str); // gives false


if(eid_str_in .equals(comp_str ))
{
    System.out.println("true");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("false");
}
}
%>
```

Can anyone help me getting through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct usage around String is:

```
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;
...
    current_user_eid = new String(msg, offset, length, charset);
} 
else
    return;

length = msg[off+1]*256 + msg[off];
offset = msg[off+3]*256 + msg[off+2];
current_user_eid = new String(msg, offset, length, charset);
length = msg[off+9]*256 + msg[off+8];
offset = msg[off+11]*256 + msg[off+10];
current_user_eid = new String(msg, offset, length, charset);
//current system user name "yaseer"

// String Comparison starts here....

String hard_str = "yaseer"; // 

String eid_str = current_user_eid; //passing the fetched username which is yaseer
String eid_str_in = eid_str.intern(); // system username 

String comp_str = "yaseer"; // String for comparison

System.out.println(hard_str_in == comp_str); // give true

System.out.println(eid_str_in == comp_str); // gives false
System.out.println(eid_str_in.equals(comp_str));
// gave true ("on screen"), expected to give false
```

The last two lines would give different results if I understand you correctly.

That should not be so for a pure ASCII "yaseer" (assuming you do not work on an AS/400 with EBCDIC with wrong java source/java compiler encodings).

However I saw `current_user_eid` being assigned twice, the first time with 6 bytes, which could correspond to "yaseer" with 6 letters.

So I assume that the second `current_user_eid` is a mix-up.

Dumping a String for its value:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(eid_str_in.toCharArray()));
```

For the rest: `.intern()` is no longer something to use w.r.t. efficiency; hence also not `==`. In earlier versions, the interned constants went to a "permanent memory generation" of limited size which had its drawbacks, if too much and too often was interned.

Bytes always are converted to the Unicode `String`'s `char`s (UTF-16), possibly using the platform default Charset. So better explicitly provide the `Charset`, even `Charset.defaultCharset()` as that states explicitly the platform dependency.

Comment: If the length is 12, then it is probably UTF-16LE. One simply cannot tell anything sensible; log/debug.

Comment: The OP said in the last reply to my comment that the returned string had embedded nul characters. This would imply it's encoded as UTF16LE (which is typical on Windows) rather than ISO 8859-1.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thanks for the confirmation I was not sure, but thought so. `StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE` then as Charset.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException and "Joop" you  guys saved my days.. Thanks its working now ... with `StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE` Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) String literals will stored in String constant pool. Here value cannot be duplicated. For example if you are trying to create two variables with same values, the second variable value cannot be store in SCP instead it will get first value address.

2) But using **new String** two object will be created even though both object has same values.

Example:

```
public class TestFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name1 = "AAA";
        String name2 = name1.intern();

        String name3 = new String("AAA");
        String name4 = name3.intern();

        System.out.println(name1 == name2); // true
        System.out.println(name2 == name4); // true

        System.out.println(name3 == name4); // false
        System.out.println(name3.equals(name4));
    }   
}
```

1) H
ere name1 and name2 both are literals. so comparison will be True.

2) name3 is object but we are using intern() so will get values of the object which will be stored in name4 as a literal. so comparsion will be True.

3) But name3 and name4 comaprsion will be False. because name3 is object and name4 is literal. but it will be true if you are using .equals().

Comment: Your statements are all true, but they don't represent the problem the OP is asking about. Which is that he's comparing two *interned* strings (just like name2 == name4), which he expects to be equal (because they *appear* the same on the screen), but are not in fact equal.

Comment: you are right @DodgyCodeException i feel the string value in current_user_eid variable has some issue for using  "new String(msg, offset, length)" ? where msg is in bytes. as expected ("yaseer".equals(current_user_eid)) conditions gives false with or without using intern(). where they are exactly same in S.O.P :(